C++ continue base class bitfield in derived class
I have a base class with a bitfield
enum Enum {
 ENUM1,
 ENUM2,
 ...
 ENUM8
};

struct Base {
  Enum type : 3;
};

I am inheriting a class
struct Derived : public Base {
 bool bf1 :  1;
 u32  bf2 : 19,
 u32  bf1 :  9;
};

I need to ensure that the memory space for the Derived class is 4 bytes (I have a 32-bit microcontroller), since there will be several inherited classes and they need to be serialized, and when unpacking by the 'type' field, understand how to process the remaining bit fields .
Is this method reliable? If not, how can we do it better?
My CLang compiler does package everything correctly, but I'm not sure about the reliability of this result.

Bitfields are implementation specific. It is hard to ensure what you want in a portable way, but if you know what is your CPU and compiler, I think your approach is OK. At least place a static_assert(sizeof(Derived)==4); in your code.

The standard gives no guarantees for this. You are in Implementation defined territory.

The underlying type of Enum is also implementation-defined, although not larger than int. You can fix the underlying type by writing e.g. enum Enum : int { /*...*/ };. And u32 is not a standard type. You must have defined it somewhere yourself or in a library. The standard type is named uint32_t.

Bitfields do not do what you think they do. The only ensure you have a variable that behaves like it has N number of bits (it doesn't promise much about how it is stored in memory). For real bitwise operations you will have to make a type of known size and use shifts and masks. And then don't use an enum, but just constexpr <some_type> bit1 = 0x01; in a namespace

Is this method reliable?  Limited reliability.  It's at the mercy of the compiler implementation, which can vary by platform or by compiler.  I avoid it (because my code runs on a lot of different platforms), and code my bit twiddling explicitly. If not, how can we do it better?  Do your own bit twiddling.
